# Number Format Exception within a Class

Tags: java

I think my issue here is a dumb, syntaxical issue, but here it is. I'm writing a program that takes  CSV file which is 3 rows of 4 columns of numbers. I take that file in as a paramater at runtime, I then split at the newline character (\n) and then split at the comma seperator. I then store this into a "2D Array" of String type. I then take every value, parse to double, and fill a 2nd "2D Array" but of double this time. Everything works nicely.

My issue is when I tried to take all of that code and put into it's own class. I added a constructor to the main, and in the class I copied and pasted the previously working code. But now when parsing from string to double, I get the NumberFormatException when going from the 4th to 5th element. Exact same code works when coded in the main.

I think my knowledge of classes is my issue here.

Here is the class I am making:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class DataMatrix {

    private double[][] dMatrix; 

    public DataMatrix(String text) {

        String[] line = text.split("\n");
        // Creates an array for the CSV file
        String[][] sMatrix = new String[line.length][];

        for(int i=0; i < line.length; i++)
            sMatrix[i] = text.split(",");
        System.out.println("Original String: ");

        for(int x=0; x < sMatrix.length; x++) {
            for(int j=0; j <= line.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(sMatrix[x][j]);
            }
        }

        double[][] dMatrix = new double[sMatrix.length][];
        System.out.println("Converted to double: ");

        for(int x=0; x < sMatrix.length; x++) {
            dMatrix[x] = new double[sMatrix[x].length];
            for(int j=0; j <= sMatrix.length; j++) {

                dMatrix[x][j] = Double.parseDouble(sMatrix[x][j]);
                System.out.println(dMatrix[x][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main (ignore comments, using them when I copy/paste stuff out of it):

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Assignment1{
    public static void main(String[] args){

//  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");   

        //Make sure the user passed the command line argument - and nothing else
        if (args.length != 1){
            System.out.println("Assignment1 takes exactly one command-line argument.");
            System.out.println("Usage: java Assignment1 some_file.csv");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String csvFileName = args[0];

        //Instantiate my custom file reader
    CSVReader fileReader = new CSVReader();

        //Read the file into a string
        String text = fileReader.readFile(csvFileName);
    DataMatrix matrix = new DataMatrix(text);  

}//end of main
}//end of class
```

EDIT: Here is my output:

```
Files contents:
1,2,3,4
3,4,1,0
2,3,4,2

Original String:
1
2
3
4
3
4
1
0
2
3
4
2

Converted to double:
1.0
2.0
3.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 3"

at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
at DataMatrix.<init>(DataMatrix.java:30)
at Assignment1.main(Assignment1.java:22)
```

Comment: Provide the line of csv input that fails. To make reproducing the error easier, temporarily add debug output
        String doubleString=sMatrix[x][j];
        try {
          Double.parseDouble(doubleString);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
          System.out.println("NFE on:"+doubleString);
        }

Comment: Isn't this line `sMatrix[i] = text.split(",");` supposed to be `sMatrix[i] = line[i].split(",");` ?

Comment: Edited my post to show output error.

Comment: @SanketMakani Oh wow, I wrote the wrong variable there. I guess this is what happens when you stare at your code for too long. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `dMatrix` in the constructor hide the attribute `dMatrix`

Simply change `double[][] dMatrix = new double[sMatrix.length][];` in the constructor code by `dMatrix = new double[sMatrix.length][];`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When doing that, I now get a NullPointException error.

Comment: Don't remove the whole line. You have just declared the `2-D Array` globally . Still you need to provide it the reference so change that line with `dMatrix = new double[sMatrix.length][];` @NickM

Comment: @SanketMakani When I do that, I get the same sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal) error. Line 30 in DataMatrix.java and line 22 in Assignment1.java

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there are too many things that are not quite right in your current version of the program. I will try to simplify it. You can compare it with yours and learn the mistakes:

```
import java.lang.*;

public class DataMatrix {

    public DataMatrix(String text) {
        //Replace the new line character (\n or \\r or \r\n) with a comma and split based on comma.
        String[] numbers = text.replaceAll("\r?\n|\r", ",").split(",");
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
           System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]));

    }
}
```